# Symfony 3.3 demo project

Tags: symfony, controller, symfony-3.3

I just downloaded the skeleton of symfony 3.3 version dev to try to play a little with the next version that comes on November, Symfony 4, as this link explain http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-demo.html.

I'm not able to create a simple controller and do a "Hello world".

I just create a DemoController.php with this code inside obviously the Controller folder:

```
namespace App\Controller;//namespace App;      <- WHAT I SHOULD PUT HERE?

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DemoController extends Controller
{

    public function demoAction()
    {
         return new Response("asdasd");
    }
}
```

Could anyone write what I should add to the routes.yaml? I decided in this case to not use annotations and use the routes.yaml. The route requested should be "/demo". I tried this...

```
index:
    path:     /demo
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\DemoController::demo' }
```

I guess could be in this last part the problem.

Beside that, should I modify the bundles.php?
I tried this...

```
return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    App\Controller::class => ['all' => true], <- NOT SURE IF IT'S LIKE THIS...
];
```

Comment: Did you also install the web server and cli components?  If not, I assume you have a web server of some sort configured?  Remove the controller line from bundles.php.  The services.yaml file automatically picks up controllers under the App\Controller directory which is where your controller should be.  Your route looks okay.

Comment: Oops.  Controllers go under src/Controller not src/App/Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more or less minimalist example of using Symfony Flex 3.3.10 following the first portion of: http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-demo.html

```
composer create-project "symfony/skeleton:^3.3" flex33_10
cd flex33_10
composer require webserver
composer require cli
```

Add the controller

```
# src/Controller/DemoController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
#se Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DemoController extends AbstractController
{
    public function demoAction()
    {
        return new Response('aaabbb');
    }
}
```

Add the route

```
# config/routes.yaml
demo:
    path: /demo
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\DemoController::demoAction' }
```

Now clear the cache (because of the newly added route) and start the server

```
bin/console cache:clear    
bin/console server:start
# browse to: http://127.0.0.1:8001/demo
```

And hopefully all will be well.

Note that when defining a route you need to spell out the complete action method name demoAction vs demo.  Less magic.

Note that for new apps your controllers should extend AbstractController instead of the old base Controller.  AbstractController still gives you all of your favorite controller helper functions but restricts access to the container.  You will need to inject any additional services that the controller needs.

Fun stuff.  Enjoy.

Comment: Yeees! Cheers mate! Now I can have fun playing with Symfony 4 :)